# python.exe in powershell is constant, but should not

Tags: windows, powershell

I'm writing script that will detect local Python installation (or install Python, if none exists) on Win10 22H2 (MSDN, no custom build or sth). I tried to do so:

```
Write-Host "You selected path on: $pythonPath"
$pythonExecutable = "$pythonPath\python.exe"

# Check if .exe at selected path exists
if (-Not (Test-Path $pythonExecutable)) {
    # No python.exe found, installing it..
} else {
    Write-Host "Python version detected:"
    & $pythonExecutable --version
}
```

After selecting any of the paths options that i have (all 10 are valid - checked all of them in file explorer):

```
1: D:\pythonProject\testing\venv\Scripts
2: D:\Visual Studio 2022\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\VC\SecurityIssueAnalysis\pyt
hon
3: D:\work_projects\python\<project name 3>\venv\Scripts
.. some other valid paths ..
10: D:\work_projects\python\<project name 10>\.venv\Scripts
```

I get following error (e.g. selected option #1 above):

```
You selected path on: D:\pythonProject\testing\venv\Scripts
Python version detected:
python.exe : No Python at 
'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe'
At C:\Users\User\Desktop\proj\start.ps1:70 char:5
+     & $pythonExecutable --version
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (No Python at 'C...310\python.exe':String) [], 
    RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

I tried to select wrong paths that obviously lead to installing of python.exe in current directory, but in the very end, i get same error as above EXACTLY with path specified as `'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe'`.

How do i start python.exe with selected path in PowerShell correctly?

What i want exactly, is to execute following line (with selected option #1):

```
D:\pythonProject\testing\venv\Scripts\python.exe --version
```

---

P.S. Well, i also tried:

```
$pythonExecutable = Join-Path -Path $pythonPath -ChildPath "python.exe"
...
Write-Host "Python version detected:"
    & $pythonExecutable --version
```

Unfortunately, outcome is the same :(

---

P.S.2

On a side note, when i try to execute required command directly, i get:

```
PS C:\Users\User> D:\pythonProject\testing\venv\Scripts\python.exe --version

D:\pythonProject\testing\venv\Scripts\python.exe : No Python at 
'C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe'
At line:1 char:1
+ D:\pythonProject\testing\venv\Scripts\python.exe --version
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (No Python at 'C...310\python.exe':String) [], 
    RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
```

Comment: Have you checked the shown paths if they contain a python.exe? Also check if the Python.exe file name is correct. Since Python 2 is deprecated the installation should bea Python 3 and thus the executable is often called `python3.exe`.

Comment: @Robert yep, did it right after discovering the error in post. I use PyCharm and it autogenerates venv without `python3.exe`, the only possible being `python.exe`, that displays: `Python 3.11.7 (tags/v3.11.7:fa7a6f2, Dec  4 2023, 19:24:49) [MSC v.1937 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`